# How to get rid of weird id error using react-beautiful-dnd?

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

Right now I have a page that looks like this:

[image]


Im displaying some `ClosedExerciseComp`-components basically small cards with their respective id on them. When I press the `Add exercise`-button a new exercise card will emerge.


Using react-beautiful-dnd the cards are fully drag-and-droppable.
However sometimes when I drop an Item I get this error:

[image]


It seems to occur at random when I drop an Item but I can get the error to trigger more reliable if I spam drag-and-drop in the small gap between the cards. I demonstrate [here](https://youtu.be/fzA_Ii-mX08).


My code looks like this (I know it's a tad long) (simplified aesthetically):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import ExerciseComp from "../components/ExerciseComp/ExerciseComp";

const EditorMainPage = () => {
    const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([]);

    const addExercise = () => {
        const exercise = {
            id: "exercise-" + Date.now(),
            ...,
        };
        setExercises((exercises) => [...exercises, exercise]);
    };

    const handleDragEnd = (result) => {
        if (!result.destination) return;
        if (result.destination.index === result.source.index) return;
        const items = [...exercises];
        const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
        items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
        setExercises(items);
    };

    const Exercises = () => {
        return (
            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
                <Droppable droppableId="exercises-dnd">
                    {(provided) => (
                        <div
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                            {...provided.droppableProps}
                        >
                            {exercises.map((exercise, index) => (
                                <Draggable
                                    key={exercise.id}
                                    draggableId={exercise.id}
                                    index={index}
                                >
                                    {(provided) => (
                                        <div
                                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                                            {...provided.draggableProps}
                                            {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                        >
                                            <ExerciseComp
                                                id={exercise.id}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    )}
                                </Draggable>
                            ))}
                            {provided.placeholder}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Exercises />
            <button onClick={() => addExercise()}>Add exercise</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default EditorMainPage;
```

I hope you can help me understand why suddenly react decides that an existing draggable doesn't exist???

Comment: A minor tangent note... ideally your IDs (if used as an ID attribute) should start alpha (though this restriction was lifted in HTML5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility -- MDN)

Comment: Thanks and noted. I changed this line `id: Date.now()` to this `id: "exercise-" + Date.now()`. But yeah, it didn't affect anything the error remains...